# Is it possible to show the current history line number when performing reverse search in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and typing `py` results in:

```
(reverse-i-search) `py´: python
```

I would like it to be this way:

```
(reverse-i-search) `py´: n python
```

where n is the history line number. I did not find an option in `man bash` (and wasn't surprised to find nothing, since it is a bit specific). Is there a way to achieve this by only editing the `.bashrc`?

Comment: Whats the use case? How about duplicate entries?

Comment: Isn't the point of searching when one doesn't know number?

Comment: When reverse-searching, i find it helpful to know how far back i am currently. It would only be there to give me an estimate of how far back it is.

Answer (score 1):

If there was an option to control the format of what you see during a history i-search, it would be documented in the man page.  Since you didn't find such an entry, there probably isn't one.

It would probably be implemented as a `shopt` toggle setting, or as `PS6` or something for a format string.

I agree this would be a neat UI feature, to help you know what you'll find if you up/down arrow from that point in history.

You should email the suggestion to bug-bash@gnu.org.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/.